# Don't Spin Up Entire RAID for Read Access

Tags: hard-disk, power-management, mdadm, software-raid, raid1

I have a RAID 1 managed by `mdadm` consisting of a thumb drive and an external HDD. I set a spin-down time for the external HDD.

If I access the file system of the RAID to read but not to write (for example listing the contents of a directory or printing the contents of a file), I'd like it if the HDD didn't spin up. In my configuration, there isn't even a speed advantage reading from both the thumb drive and the HDD compared to only reading from the thumb drive so no distinction between reading a little and reading a lot has to be made.

Currently, if I read from the RAID FS, I can see the result of the read instantly without the HDD spinning. Then, after about 5 seconds (the read can be over by then if it only takes a split-second like executing `ll`), the HDD spins up.

Is it possible to tell `mdadm` to only access the thumb drive for reading, not the external HDD?

Comment: in raid 1 you may set the hdd to write mostly http://superuser.com/a/384586/195171 - if it still wakes up then you are writing (maybe `noatime` will help)

Comment: @frostschutz Setting it to write mostly doesn't work. I merely opened an ssh session, `cd`d into the folder where the RAID FS is mounted to, and executed `ll`. Does that do any writing action? It behaved just like before: It showed me the output of `ll` instantly without the HDD spinning. Then, after about 5 seconds, the HDD began to spin up.

Comment: That means it's not `ll` which is causing the drive to spin up (unless it's updating `atime` on the directories perhaps?). [`iosnoop`](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/iosnoop) should help you figure out why your drive is spinning up...

Comment: No, `atime` isn't updated by `ll`. But I think the problem is solved. I tried it several times before posting this question and it spun up every time. But I only tried it once after setting the HDD in the RAID to writemostly. Maybe that was a false positive or it took the RAID software some time to do the change because I can't replicate it right now with `ll`. I first thought it might be due to the OS caching the contents of the folder I executed `ll` in so I executed `dd` to `/dev/null` from a file in the RAID FS and the HDD spun up after 5 to 10 seconds. But dd changes `atime`. Thank you!

Comment: @frostschutz Do you want to post this as an answer?